# Lebesgue Measurable eqality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that $E$ is measurable if and only if for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a closed set $F$  with $F\subset E$ and $m^*(E-F)\leq\varepsilon$. How do I prove it ?

Comment: See http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-regularity-properties-of-the-lebesgue-measure

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).